# Why does .find()-ing child nodes with specific parents (or descendants) with jQuery cause DOM changes?

Tags: jquery, dom, find, reflow

Using Chrome's dev tools, I have come to understand that a flashing node in the dev tools is because of a change in the DOM. Does that also lead to a reflow?

There seems to be a functional difference between the following despite the results containing the same elements:

```
var as1 = $("body").find("tr a");         // Causes <body> to flash
var as2 = $("body").find("tr").find("a"); // No flash
```

You can see this behaviour in following snippet. If you navigate to the inner `<body>` tag you will see regular flashes (in Chrome dev tools). The flashes would be irregular due to the out of sync intervals if both methods were causing a DOM change.

```js
setInterval(function() { 
    var a = $("body").find("tr a"); 
    console.log("See Chrome dev tools for synchronous flash with this message."); 
}, 2000);

setInterval(function() { var a = $("body").find("tr").find("a"); }, 1700);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
<table>
<tr><td><a href=#>Hello</a></td></tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: A DOM breakpoint on the body which breaks for subtree modifications does not get hit while the body flashes. So I guess there are no actual DOM modifications after all.

Comment: I can see both `find("tr a")` and `find("tr").find("a")` cause the flashing in my Chrome dev tool.

Comment: But an attribute modification breakpoint does get hit twice, once by [this line](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.7.1/jquery.js#L5061) and once on [this line](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.7.1/jquery.js#L5827) (tested here on SO, therefore v1.7.1).

Comment: Do attribute modifications lead to page reflows?